# Object.keys returns Empty Array

Tags: javascript

[image]

I have an object which is designed like this. I want to get the keys of the object inside the date (2020-04-01) but when i use `Object.keys(obj.array[0])` it returns me an Empty Array. I have tried using the `getOwnPropertyNames()` function but it still returns me an Empty Array.

I am doing it like this:

The object is passed to this function by another function.

```
function formatAsString(obj){
    let array = Object.keys(obj);
    for(i=0;i<array.length;i++){
        let data = Object.keys(obj[array[i]]);
        console.log(data);
        for(x=0;x<Object.keys(data).length;x++){
            let date = array[x];
            let activity = data["activity"];
            let type = data["type"];
            let company = data["company"];
            let string = `${type}( Activity : ${activity} | Comapny : ${comapny} )`;
            console.log(string);
        }
    }
}
```

I managed to make another function

```
function formatAsString(obj){
    let values = Object.values(obj);
    let dates = Object.keys(obj);
    let array = Object.keys(values);
    let activityObj = {};
    for(i=0;i<array.length;i++){
        let keys = Object.keys(values[array[i]]);
        let data = values[array[i]];
        for(x=0;x<keys.length;x++){
            let date = dates[i];
            let type = data[keys[x]].type;
            let activity = data[keys[x]].activity;
            let company = data[keys[x]].company;
            let string = `${type} -> ${activity}, ${company} <br>`;
            activityObj[date + x] = string;
        }
    }
    console.log(activityObj);
}
```

This function works when i use it in the console with the same object but doesn't work when i use  it with the function. It returns me an empty array the object `activityObj`

Comment: Can you share some data to reproduce the issue?

Comment: In order to get proper help, please proper provide us with the object

Comment: You're calling the property "array" of some object, yet I don't see the identifier "array" anywhere in your print screen. It's unclear what object you're trying to get the keys from.

Comment: This question is not clear. Please post a sample object to explain the issue better. No need to post thousands of object having more nested data. Just a simple structure that could reproduce your issue.

Comment: Please share some data or sample object to explain the issue better

Comment: Sorry i couldn't edit the answer, I have provided more information in the edited answer.

Comment: I meant i wasnt able to edit the answer.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

the best way to get the answer is to give ALL the details explaining what the problem you faced with in the very beggining. Input data examples, format of output data etc. Of course, if you really need help.
Anyway, I am pretty sure this is what you are looking for (I made it through reduce, as it's better way to work with arrays than for loop.

```
function formatAsString (obj) {
  return Object.keys(obj).reduce((str, date) => {
    const activities = Object.keys(obj[date]).reduce((strDate, key) => {
      const act = obj[date][key]
      return `${strDate} ${act.type}( Activity : ${act.activity} | Company : ${act.company} )\n`
    }, '')
      return `${str}${date}:\n${activities}`
  }, '')
}
```

Comment: It returns undefined. Because the dates are inside an object.

Comment: You firstly described a problem like 'I want to get the keys of the object inside the date'. As for me, it means that you already have an object containing full details of date.

Comment: I have attached a image with how the object looks like. Can you please have a look at that object and help me?

Comment: can you show an output example? what are you expecting to get finally?

Comment: I want to get the activity, type and company

Comment: I have updated the answer